# Specify the sheet name in SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax

Is this a valid expression for Google App Script?

```js
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("sheet1!G(B2): Z(B2)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a valid expression. You need to get a sheet before getting a range.

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1").getRange("G1:Z1").getValues();
```

If you want to use the value in cell B2 as a row value, then your code should look like this

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var rowVaue = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
var values = sheet.getRange("G" + rowVaue + ":Z" + rowVaue).getValues();
```